# Google Chrome unable to print images stored in file system using JAVA Output Stream

Tags: java, google-chrome, jquery-plugins

I have a grails application which prints reports and certificates and I am trying to print a portion of html using jQuery printElement. My Html consist of watermark logos as well as some images which is not part of the application but stored in the server file system. Although i am able to print  properly (pdf as well as using a printer) in Firefox , I have a problem printing in Google Chrome. My images and logos are not part of application rather the images are stored in a file system and are transferred to the browser using Java outputStreams. All the images are displayed properly in chrome but when I try to print to a file or using a printer using jQuery printElement , its unable to print the images which is showing in the html page, rather it prints without the images.

I am using html img tag to print, also when I try to print local images stored in the server context using the following codes it prints well in chrome

```
<img src="${resource(dir:'images',file:'exclamation.png')}" alt="" />
```

but when i tries to access the file system images using the following code snippet, its unable to print images although its displayed in the html page.

```
<img src="${createLink(action:'getImage', controller:'image')}?image=${logoPath}"/>
```

which is rendered in html as

```
<img src="/myApp/image/getImage?image=/home/dave/pictures/logo.png" >
```

where logoPath is the image's absolute path stored in the server file system.
I have also tried using absolute attribute of `<img>` but its of no help.

I am able to print it in Firefox but not in chrome . And for that reason I have restricted the application only for Firefox and it will be of great help if I could get it to work with google chrome also .

Using

apache tomcat 6 , 
JAVA 1.6 , 
grails 1.3.7 , jquery.printElement.min.js,
Google Chrome 23 (linux as well as windows 7) ,
Firefox 16 , 17

Comment: why not copy the image from file system to server context using your java output stream and then displaying it.Using output stream every time may be heavy and your stream should not download file from file system if its already present.Just a suggestion :)

Comment: The images need not necessarily be in the file system also , it  also can be in a remote System.Copying the images or storing the images inside the server context does not seem like a good idea as the images are bound to increase and storing say 100 gb(just an assumption)  of images inside the tomcat web-app folder does not seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: After doing some digging , i found that , the image are fetched by chrome only after the print window is closed. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I found a solution that works for me in chrome. 
I switched from jquery.printElement.min.js to jquery.printElement.js and followed the author's suggestion.

https://github.com/erikzaadi/jQuery.printElement/issues/2

In jquery.printElement.js

REPLACE:

```
documentToWriteTo.open();
documentToWriteTo.write(html);
documentToWriteTo.close();
_callPrint(popupOrIframe);
```

WITH:

```
documentToWriteTo.onload = _callPrint(popupOrIframe);
documentToWriteTo.open();
documentToWriteTo.write(html);
documentToWriteTo.close();
```

I tried the above suggestion and still i was unable to print images . So i changed the timeout in _callPrint(element) function of the js and set the timeout to 75 instead of 50 and it was printing all the images.